# Why is $d(xdx) = 0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

If the idea behind the exterior derivative $d$ is that it tells us how quickly a $k$-form changes along every possible direction, why is $d(xdx)=0$ even though $xdx$ *varies* with $x$?

I understand the mechanics of exterior calculus but I'm trying to understand the intuition behind why it's the right tool for "differentiating" vector fields, rather than say working with vector-differences like a standard derivative (e.g. $\frac {\partial\overrightarrow v}{\partial x}=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\overrightarrow v(x+h,y)-\overrightarrow v(x,y)}{h}$).

Comment: The exterior derivative does not tell us how quickly a $k$ form changes along every possible direction, that is only the interpretation assigned to the exteriror derivative of $0$ forms. The exterior derivative is measuring exactly that - how much of an "exterior" or boundary structure exists and how it changes. $x dx = d\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$ - which means that it is, in some heuristic sense, a "complete picture of a boundary" of the $0$ form.

Comment: Think of how a hemisphere has a circular boundary but does not enclose a volume A full sphere encloses a volume, but it has no line boundary. What this means for us is $d^2\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right) = 0$

Comment: $x \,\mathrm dx$ is constant when you use the right coordinates. So if you want to use this for e.g. physical theories, the result shouldn't depend on your coordinates.

Comment: A $1$-form has exterior derivative equal to $0$ if the integral of it along any closed loop is zero. For $x\,dx$, this is intuitively plausible because the increase in $x$ as you move away from the starting point on the loop cancels out with the decrease in $x$ when you return to the starting point.

Answer (score 7):

Consider a change of variables, $y = \frac12 x^2$, then $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy} = \frac 1x$. This implies $x\, \mathrm dx = \mathrm dy$, which is "constant"! This means that when we use different coordinates, we will disagree about what is "constant" for differential forms. We don't have this problem with functions: if $f$ is constant then no matter how you change variables the result is constant.

Therefore we have to accept that constancy is not a "real" concept for differential forms (unless you install additional structure called "connections" — just like how velocity is relative unless you designate a fixed body which we compare velocity to), and $\mathrm d(x\,\mathrm d x) = 0$ shouldn't be rejected solely because it is not constant from your viewpoint. In fact your first sentence is almost true: The exterior derivative shows all the "observable" rate of change of a $k$-form, and $x\,\mathrm dx$ only changes in a non-observable way.